# Single character String

Tags: java

My opinion was, until today, that a literal like `"c"` creates a `String` object. Today I heard that Java is not creating an object for single character strings. Is this right? Does it store that literal as a `char`?

Comment: This would be an interesting concept of auto-boxing/unboxing of a single-character String to a `char`...

Comment: Tell the person that told you that to go read the part about literals in the Java Language Specification. Character Literals and String Literals: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#100960

Answer (score 16):

No it's wrong. Even `""`, creates a `String` object.
However if you type `'c'`, you got a char and not a `String` object.

Answer (score 9):

`"c"` will create a string. `'c'` will create a char

Answer (score 6):

Java does create an instance of a string even for a single character string.  The following prints `java.lang.String`:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(final String[] args){
        System.out.println("c".getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it obviously does return string because `""`(double quotes)is for strings and `''` (single quotes) is for chars

Answer (score 5):

`"c"` is a `String` literal. It represents a `String` just as `"foo"` represents a `String`.

There is no special handling of single-character `String` literals (not even of the 0-letter `String` literal `""`).

Whoever told you that it's treated differently was either a.) wrong or b.) talking about something different (a library that has special treatment, for example).

Answer (score 1):

`"c"` does create an object. However, if you assign the literal again in somewhere in the source code, it will not create a new object, but reference the first string object created.

For example:

```
String s1 = "abc";   //creates the String object
String s2 = "abc";   //references the same object as s1
```

Both s1 and s2 are assigned the same object, and == would work.

You can read more here: http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/

Comment: @Woot4Moo no, that's true. literal strings are interned by default.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, I agreed with sfussenegger, all string literals are by default interned. The doc for intern() clarifies it: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29

Comment: This is still incredibly dangerous and poor.  The recommendation is to always use .equals on String comparison.  If I push the strings into a char array, null the original strings, and then rebuild the string from the array that is one way to make == fail.  Yes I realize it is not the same thing, but that is why you should use .equals

Comment: Agreed, equals() should always be instead in general for comparison instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what was meant was that the beneath the hood [flyweights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) are created (dunno how this works with Java, but I presume that this concept is employeed at some level for strings)

Comment: that's true for some operations, namely substring(..), subSequence(..) and trim(), where the resulting String will use the same char[] under the hood. I don't see how this could affect string literals though.

Answer (score 0):

`String` stores characters as a `char[]`, so most likely `"c"` will be represented as `new char[] { 'c' }` within the `String` object.

Since the `String` class is `final`, it means there is no subclass storing single-character strings in a `char c` field.

Also, there is no concept of auto-boxing/unboxing for a single-character `String` to `char` -- as far as it is documented, so it is safe to assume single-character Strings are stored similar to any other type of String.

Answer (score 0):

As with most things in programming look at the source -> java.lang.String.

All Strings are instances of java.lang.String there is no special case. Each and every java.lang.String includes a char[] and some integers to hold the start and end indexes. Note the char[] is shared between Strign instances such as when one does a String.substring() the original char[] is not cloned or copied it is shared but the start/end indexes are updated.